# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined using gatling

Tags: firefox, gatling

Hi trying to record some scenario using gatling,
 when I run my website normally it load jquery properly but not using gatling recording.
Did anyone faced such issue?

Answer (score 0):

Gatling is not a web browser.

This is important, because as far a Gatling is concerned, jQuery is just data. It's a javascript file. You can tell Gatling to download this file, but Gatling won't run it because Gatling is not a web browser.

However, there may still be a way to solve your problem with Gatling. Gatling supports CSS selectors, so may be able to do whatever you were trying to do with jQuery, if you told us what you wanted to do.